# Importing JSON_simple package problem

Tags: java, classpath, package, import

I am using JSON_simple library. I placed the jar files json-simple-1.1 and json-rpc in my classpath. It throws me a `<package not found error>.` I resolved the same issue by a method I read somewhere (to include the jars in a specific folder, which I don't remember now and hence the problem, but it was not a recommended solution). How to resolve it? I've hit the wall. Thanx..!!

Comment: "it throws me a...?" -- please rephrase. Also, I think it's a classpath issue unrelated to Json.

Comment: How did you add the jars in your "classpath"?  Are you using an IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: @Raghuram thanx. I had, in fact, messed up while adding the jars in the claspath. Stupid me, didn't realize it all this while. So, now I added the jars to jre/lib/ext :)

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

1. The jar is not really in the classpath used by the java-instance starting your program.
2. You are not referencing the correct package-name in your import-statement spelling error. For json-simple it's: `import org.json.simple` or `import org.json.simple.parser`.

From remote I cannot analyse further your problem. Try to check your import-statement. If that is right, give us more information about how you include the jar into the classpath.

Comment: package org.json does not exist

Comment: #1: The jar is not really in the classpath ... Besides that org.json is for json-simple, it may differ for the JSON-library of your choice.